# Getting mismatching height values mobile safari - same device but different iOS version

Tags: javascript, iphone, web, mobile-safari, ios14

I just wondering why am getting different value for

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

For example:
when in landscape iPhone 11 - iOS < 14.2 gives 414 in css pixel
but,
when in landscape iPhone 11 - iOS > 14.2 gives 364 in css pixel

Is there anything changed with above iOS 14.2 versions?

Comment: `document.documentElement.clientHeight` in iOS 14.5 on iPhone X gives `292px`

Comment: But in iOS 11 on iPhone X gives 375px.